# How to combine evidence of existence vs non-existence in distance measurement?

Tags: probability-distributions

In my scenario, I have a map of 2d points and a set of disjoint circles of radius 5 that are on the map. I'm shooting a laser beam from position (0,0) at some angle until I shoot a circle. The probability of observing the circle is 1 along its whole area.
The goal is to find the probability distribution of the circle occupancy after a single shot. In other words: what is the probability that if I shoot at some position, I will hit a circle?

In the single laser distance measurement, assuming I have a perfect sensor, along the shot there is a single point of object hit and multiple points of miss. [Let's assume I've hit some circle shooting from point (0,0) along the x-axis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PxiY.png)

After a shot, I have 1 point of existence evidence and multiple points of free space evidence. Let's separate them into a "hit" point and "miss" points.

I can use my circle model (where I have a probability of hit = 1 inside the circle) to construct all probable [circle center positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqiml.png) and make sure I multiply it by 1 - [positions free of circle centers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aript.png). This leaves me with [the probable circle centers that could have been observed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkqw2.png). The sum of those points should be 1.

Now using convolution with kernel as my model, I can construct [all the places possibly occupied by those circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Qkx.png) and [all the free places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYKfX.png).

The question is how to combine those two distributions. I need to end up with a probability of 0 on the left of the contact point and 1 on the right. The only way I can think of is to use:

> occupancy = existance - (1-existance) * free

That gives me [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stVmq.png), which I can scale into 0-1. I think about it as:

> For each point of the map, if the probability of existance is not 100%, the rest from 100% is either empty or unknown, which are both calculated in the other plot.

But is there any mathematical equation that I can use to prove that what I'm doing is correct? And am I correct with that reasoning?

The other question is: What if I have another shot 1 pixel below the hit spot? How can I combine those two observations? I know that I could transform it into the log odds, add the new observation, and transform it back to the probabilities, but because of 0s and 1s, I will have some -inf and inf numbers...

Comment: What's the underlying model here? There's a _single_ radius-5 circle and you want to estimate where it is? There's _some set_ of radius-5 circles (known to be disjoint? possibly overlapping?) and you want to estimate their union? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated the description

Comment: That's clearer, thanks! It's still not _entirely_ clear. E.g., a process that always just makes one circle and then stops is consistent with your description, and so is one that places a circle and then tries to place another at random and just keeps on until there is no space left where another circle could go, etc.

Comment: the circles are already spread in the environment. I don't know where they are. By shooting the laser I can do the observations and that's how I want to calculate the occupancy map of the existing circles.